# How to store int values in numpy.empty array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As the following code shows, `empty` array replaces my int values with float ones. How can I prevent this?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.empty(3)
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
print a
```

Output:

```
[1., 2., 3.]
```

Comment: As a side note: Is there a reason you need to use `empty` and then fill in the values one by one, instead of just doing `a = np.array([1, 2, 3])`? That would have avoided the problem you're seeing, as the default `dtype` for an array constructed from a sequence is determined by the values of the sequence, so you would have gotten `int`; when it doesn't know the values, it doesn't have any information, so it has to default to `float`.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the asking but the point is I need to calcualte the values and I need a `for` loop for that. The problem is it doesn't do it always. For example `numpy.asarray()` will keep the format!

Comment: That's exactly the point: `asarray` or `array` _can_ keep the type, because it _knows_ the type; `empty` _can't_ keep the type, because it _doesn't_. (Also, you can easily turn your `for` loop into an iterator, e.g., by wrapping it in a generator function, and then pass the iterator to, e.g., `np.fromiter`. Or, of course, build a `list` to pass to `np.array` instead.)

Comment: [This pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g9A7PLry) shows what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the dtype when you call `np.empty`:

```
a = np.empty(3, dtype='int')
```

---

If you do not specify a dtype, the default is float. This is the call signature of `np.empty`:

```
empty(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
```

Comment: But why does it cast it to float automatically?!?!

Comment: Every NumPy array has a dtype. The default is `float`.

Comment: That seems nut always to be true, or maybe I am confused because for example `numpy.asarray()` will keep the format of int if the values are integer.

Comment: @Naji: It's always true. I explained this in my comment. When it knows the type you want while constructing the array, it can use that type. When it doesn't know the type you want until later, it has to guess the type at construction time, and it always guesses `float`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `dtype=int`:

```
>>> a = np.empty(3, dtype=np.int)
>>> a[0]=1
>>> a[1]=2
>>> a[2]=3
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
```

As the default value for `dtype` is `float` for `numpy.empty`, so your assigned values gets converted to `float`.

```
empty(...)
    empty(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
```